# Opening a window on top of other windows

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

How to open a window on top of other windows when calling a function?

```
import wx
def openFile(wildcard="*"):
    app = wx.App(None)
    style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, 'Open', wildcard=wildcard, style=style)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dialog.GetPath()
    else:
        dialog.Destroy()
        path = 'No file'
        return f'<div class="notification error">{path}</div>'
    dialog.Destroy()
    return f'<div id="pathToFile" class="notification">{path}</div>'
```

Comment: This is only partial code. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Accepted answer from @VZ is spot on for all normal usage but strictly speaking, your code can be tweaked to work, even if it serves no real purpose but you'll notice, despite passing `wx.STAY_ON_TOP`, it will not honour it.

Like so:

```
import wx
def openFile(wildcard="*"):
    app = wx.App(None)
    style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST | wx.STAY_ON_TOP
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, 'Open', wildcard=wildcard, style=style)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dialog.GetPath()
    else:
        path = 'No file'
    dialog.Destroy()
    return f'<div class="notification error">{path}</div>'

print(openFile())
```

Answer (score 0):

To show a dialog on top of some other top level window you need to specify that window as the dialog parent (instead of using `None` as you do).

There is no support for showing a native dialog, such as the "Open file" one, on top of all windows, this can only be done for custom windows using `wx.STAY_ON_TOP` flag.